# python matplotlib styles: How to make custom colored markers + lines using matlab style format string

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using MATLAB-style formating to change the style of plot lines, like

```
mystyle = '-r.'
ax1.plot(x1, y1, mystyle)
ax2.plot(x2, y2, mystyle)
...
axN.plot(xN, yN, mystyle)
```

which draws red line + red dot markers. But how do I specify grey color for lines + markers **using MATLAB string?**
If it is not feasible, what `mystyle` should look like so that I can control style of all plots sharing it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply define all properties separately. As **grey** doesn't exist as predefined color, you need to use an normalized RGB-vector, like `[0.2 0.2 0.2]`

```
x = 1:42;
y = sin(x);

plot(x, y, 'color',[0.2 0.2 0.2],'LineStyle','-','Marker','.')
```

---

if you want multiple plots with the same style you can save it an cell array and access it with an [**comma-separated-list**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
grey = [0.2 0.2 0.2];
myStyle = {'color',grey,'LineStyle','-','Marker','.','MarkerEdgeColor',grey,'MarkerFaceColor',grey}

plot(x, y, myStyle{:})
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `grey = [0.2 0.2 0.2]` is not Python syntax nor `myStyle{:}`
Interpreter reports invalid syntax. But your idea is something I am looking for: unwrapping `mystyle`inside the `plot()` function

Comment: well I've never seen any python tag.

Comment: oops, sorry, I didn't mention it explicitly because I thought "matplotlib" tag is sufficient

Comment: Probably it would, but I don't know any python syntax. You probably just need to translate the syntax a little. Feel free to edit my answer that it fits the python syntax or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
plot(xdata,ydata,'.-','Color',[.5 .5 .5])
```